# ViewPager is not showing in the middle of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I added ViewPager for views(not fragments) located in the middle of the fragment, but for some reason it's not showing.

There is ViewGroup parent container for it (FrameLayout), viewpager added dynamically (also tried to insert it directly in layout).

May be I miss something.
Will be glad for any tip, thanks!

ViewPager:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

List<View> pages = null;

public TabsPagerAdapter(List<View> pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    View v = pages.get(position);
    collection.addView(v, 0);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

}
```

Fragment:

```
...
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);

    FrameLayout pagerPlaceholder = (FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_placeholder);

    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<>();
    View page = LayoutInflater.from(getDashboardActivity()).inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText("Test1");
    pages.add(page);

    View page2 = LayoutInflater.from(getDashboardActivity()).inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) page2.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView2.setText("Test2");
    pages.add(page);

    TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(pages);
    ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(getDashboardActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
    pagerPlaceholder.addView(viewPager, 0,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return root;
}
```

fragment_product.xml

```
...
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_catalog_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">
...
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">           
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the full layout please? And I guess that `getDashboardActivity()` returns `getActivity()`, isn't it? Because I can't reproduce the problem: when I changed the typo mistake (`page2` instead of `page`), I have the two views visible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and found two clues, hope this will help:

1. Did you forget to commit the transaction of `FragmentManager`?

   ```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   transaction.add(R.id.frament_container, new MyFragment());
   transaction.commit();
   ```
2. The View `page` is added to the ArrayList `pages` twice, you need to add `page2` at second `page.add(page)`.

---

I just push the demo to [github](https://github.com/leiweibo/FragmentDemo).

Comment: Thanks for mistake! 
I don't use fragments (view as object instead)

Answer (score -1):

Please using `getChildFragmentManager();` if you use NestedFragment.

Simple :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frament_container, new MyFragment());
transaction.commit();
```